# Is there a way to have a x-axis "independent" from x-values for a hboxplot in Zingchart?

Tags: zingchart

I have a selection of weathersensors from which I want to display temperature boxplots. All sensors(weatherstations) are located at various altitudes.
Is there a way to have the x-axis display steps of say 100, and place the boxplots where they "belong" based on the altitude of the sensor/station?

I have created a demo here: https://app.zingsoft.com/demos/create/1N2M7WLE 
As demonstrated, the altitudes on the x-axis gets a bit odd when just using the altitudes from the stations as values.

Regards,
Sven-Erik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a feature already implemented in the dev stage, the new public release (due end of October) will contain this feature. See below how the output will look:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I will test it as soon as it is released.

Comment: Hi Adrian. 
Has this been implemented yet? I can't find any relevant info on https://www.zingchart.com/docs/change-log#-11-18-2019- , and the demo still shows funky altitudes.

Sven-Erik

Comment: Hi, sorry, somehow i've missed this reply. The JSON needs to be slightly changed, and if you need to show only specific X values you need to use markers, but here is the updated demo: https://app.zingsoft.com/demos/view/3UOEVC0G